# It is possible to view ASP.NET MVC3 sessions in Google Chrome?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

Let's assume that we have the following piece of code:

```
Session["username"] = GetUserByCredential(username, password);
```

It is possible to view that session in Google Chrome ?
I tried to see in `Resources` tab but no success.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Session you are talking about is a *server side* datastructure inside the webserver / web application.

You cannot access that directly from the client.

You will have to send the content of the current session to the client to view it:

```
public ActionResult GetCurrentSession() {
    return View(Session);
}
```

And a view similar to this:

```
@model HttpSessionStateBase

foreach (string key in Model.Keys)
{
    @Session[key].ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The session is stored in server memory (or distributed in SQL Server depending on your setup).

Regardless of the setup the Session data will not be visible to any browser unless you specifically write it out somewhere.  This is by design and it would not be very secure if it did.